# Fragment not in kotlin but in java it works (same code)

Tags: android, kotlin

im trying to run a fragment inside a FrameLayout:

code from activity.kt:

```
...
 frag.arguments = bundle
                ft.replace(R.id.framelayout_record, frag, "feedback")
               // ft.addToBackStack(null)
                ft.commitNow()
...
```

THIS WORKS:

```
   View root;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_feedback, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage("Testtt").show();
    }
```

the alert is displayed correctly

but using this:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

        internal lateinit var root: View

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            root = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_feedback, container, false)
            return root
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage("Test Kotlin").show()
        }
    }
```

nothing happens, just show the layout but no alert and i cant access layout element

Comment: are you forgetting a call to super.onViewCreated?

Comment: @SarthakMittal lol, was that, dont know why kotlin need its but in java it was omitted, can you post as response so i can accept..

Comment: strange! I just checked and it seems that onViewCreated does not need to call super as the base class implementation is no-op, did it solved ur problem after adding?

Comment: can you try one thing: do not call super in onViewCreated, and try adding a delay to your dialog call, something like: 

Handler().postDelayed({
AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage("Test Kotlin").show()
}, 250)

Comment: or try moving the dialog `show` function to `onResume` instead?